# proving that there is no constant s.t for every continious f f in norm$ L_1$ <= f in norm $L_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

So as a part of an assignment' we had the following question:
Show that there doesn't exist any constant D>0 s.t for every continious $f:[1,b]\rightarrow R$: $ ||f||_2 \le D||f||_1 $

I searched this question and found out that I show this by providing the function:
$f= n(1-n(x-a)) , a \le x\le a+1/n$

$f = 0, otherwise$

This function does provide with the right example, but I'm not sure what is the intuition behind it. Is there something in this function that should have been clear to me that this properties will hold?, is there better way to find functions that will hold cetrine properties like this question other than guess?

Comment: The statement is completely unclear to me

Comment: So what is the statement to be proved...?

Comment: I accidently the main part of the claim I wanted to prove. Editing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean to show that there is no constant $D$ such that $||f||_2\le D ||f||_1$?

The function you provide is indeed a counterexample. You'll get a good intuition if you plot this function for a few $n$s. It starts at $n$ and falls linearly to $0$ if you move along the $x$-axis by $1/n,$ and is $0$ from then onward. So the integral, i.e., $L^1$-norm, i.e., area under the curve is the area of a rectangular triangle with short sides $n$ and $1/n;$ thus it is $1/2$ for all $n.$ However, if you look at the $L^2$ norm you have to square before integrating, and the integral becomes $n/3,$ which, even after taking the root, is unbounded. Thus, the inequality can not hold universally for some $D.$

Or to restate: for any $D$ the inequality
$$
\sqrt{\frac{n}{3}} \le D \cdot \frac{1}{2} 
$$
can not hold for all integers $n>0.$

Comment: Thanks!.
Though I'm still not sure about the intuition. I 
[plotted the graph here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5ymqkvfahz)
And I'm note sure if I understand what you were trying to tell me

Comment: Nice graphics! Try also to add the square of the functions, and observe how the area under two curves grow when you increase $n.$

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure what you are talking about. I did [plot also the square of the function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gblulblbmk)
But as I see it - If n is big enough, both lines are jus straight line on the Y axis. The only difference is that the red one (the squared func) is going to infinity faster

Comment: The area under the blue curve is constant (increasing height is exactly compensated by narrower width). For the red curve it is no longer the case, the area grows bigger than any given number, eventually, and so does $||f||_2$. Thus, we can never have $||f||_2$ bounded in terms of $||f||_1.$ Recall that the norms are integrals, and thus areas.